# Safe to alter SLURM batch file after submission?

Tags: slurm

After I submit a batch file to slurm (e.g. `qsub FILENAME`) can I alter the file without altering the submitted job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Slurm makes a copy of the submission script at the time of submission. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778844/changing-the-bash-script-sent-to-sbatch-in-slurm-during-run-a-bad-idea/38785813#38785813).