# Changing the executing (R) script sent to sbatch in slurm during run

Tags: bash, shell, distributed-computing, slurm

If I change something within the R script 'foo.R' after submitting the following job that consists multiple tasks, would the pending tasks execute the updated 'foo.R'? I believe the running tasks will not be affected, but what about the tasks that are still queuing?

```
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --job-name="S"
#SBATCH --time=7-0:00
#SBATCH --mem=15g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=1-500

Rscript foo.R
```

I saw a similar question regarding changing the bash script itself:
[Changing the bash script sent to sbatch in slurm during run a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778844/changing-the-bash-script-sent-to-sbatch-in-slurm-during-run-a-bad-idea). In my case, the change is made in the executing R file, and the bash script is unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.R` will only be picked up when the job starts, so you can modify it before then.